# Uploading Attachment to Message Replies

Tags: yammer

I'm trying to create a yammer reply message with attachments using the REST API. I add the actual message body, reply_to_id and the attachments as part of Multi part form data request and post it to yammer. I see that the reply message gets posted properly but the attachment is missing. Is this the way to post the reply and any idea on why the attachment is not getting uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Are you successfully uploading the files in advance of the post? Files on Yammer have to be uploaded first and the attachment_id attached to the message you are posting in order to put the attachment on the post.

More information is available here (for Ruby, but you didn't specify the language you're using): http://rdoc.info/github/yammer/yam/Yammer/Api/PendingAttachment

More information on pendingattachments in Yammer is available at https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-messages (search for Manipulating Messages).

Comment: I have looked at the yammer REST API documentation. I do NOT do a Pending Attachment upload. Yammer REST API suggest we can perform a multi part form data upload of attachments along with messages. I take the attachmentN route.